# Application.Match vs Find

Tags: vba, excel

I want to write a macro that will get the last item in column A and check if it exists anywhere in columns B to D. However, the following code never finds a match and returns "Doesn't exist":

```
Sub MatchInRange()

Dim LastItem As Range
Set LastItem = Range("A1").End(xlDown)

If Not IsError(Application.Match(LastItem, "B:D", 0)) Then
    MsgBox "Exists in range"
Else
    MsgBox "Doesn't exist"
End If
End Sub
```

But it works when rewritten using Find:

```
Sub FindInRange()

Dim LastItem As Range
Set LastItem = Range("A1").End(xlDown)

If Not Range("B:D").Find(LastItem) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Exists in range"
Else
    MsgBox "Doesn't exist"
End If
End Sub
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong with the first code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match works on 1 row or column. You are using 3 - **B**,**C** and **D**. Rewrite the first formula like this:

```
Sub TestMe()
    Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.match("TestValue", Range("B:B"), 0)
End Sub
```